# [ERROR] [1588286007.343230]: Current /drone/down_camera/image_raw not ready yet, retrying for getting down_camera_rgb_image_raw

Tags: ros, drone, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a script (appended to the end of this post) to setup my workspace on my Ubuntu18.04. After setting everything up I ran the following lines:

Terminal 1: `roslaunch my_parrotdrone_openai_example start_training_v2.launch`

Terminal 2: `rosrun sjtu_drone start_gui`

However I'm receiving the error:

`[ERROR] [1588286007.343230]: Current /drone/down_camera/image_raw not ready yet, retrying for getting down_camera_rgb_image_raw`

When doing a rostopic list, I only have the following /drone related topics available:

```
/drone/down_camera/image_raw
/drone/gt_acc
/drone/gt_pose
/drone/gt_vel
/drone/imu
/drone/land
/drone/posctrl
/drone/reset
/drone/sonar
/drone/takeoff
/drone/vel_mode
```

When looking at the [source code](https://theconstructcore.bitbucket.io/openai_ros/_modules/openai_ros/robot_envs/parrotdrone_env.html), it appears there are a lot of missing camera topics.

When I run different non-openai launch file, i.e., `roslaunch sjtu_drone contest.launch`, all topics are available.

How do I fix the missing-topic issue?

Setup Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

# Get Base Packages
mkdir -p ~/simulation_ws/src
cd ~/simulation_ws/src
git clone -b version2 https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_ros.git
git clone -b version2 https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_examples_projects.git
git clone -b kinetic-gazebo9 https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/parrot_ardrone.git
sed -i "s/user/$USER/g" ~/simulation_ws/src/openai_examples_projects/my_parrotdrone_openai_example/config/*v2.yaml

# Install Dependencies
# sudo rosdep init # run this line if first time running
rosdep update
rosdep install --from-paths . -i

# Build
cd ~/simulation_ws
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
rospack profile

cd $DIR
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351101/%5Berror%5D-%5B1588286007.343230%5D:-current-/drone/down_camera/image_raw-not-ready-yet,-retrying-for-getting-down_camera_rgb_image_raw/) by [ltbd78](https://answers.ros.org/users/53077/ltbd78/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-01**:
I would really suggest you post an issue on the `theconstructcore` repositories, as it would appear almost all packages you use come from there.

The chances their devs/maintainers/instructors see you post here are rather slim.

If you do end up posting on their issue trackers, please post a comment here with a link to your issue, so we can keep things connected.

**Comment by [ltbd78](https://answers.ros.org/users/53077/ltbd78/) on 2020-05-01**:
Just posted. Here's the [link](https://bitbucket.org/theconstructcore/openai_examples_projects/issues/4/error-1588286007343230-current-drone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved: Issue was due to running `roslaunch my_parrotdrone_openai_example start_training_v2.launch` in a ssh terminal rather than from the VM itself. The full list of ROS topics becomes available when using terminal within VM.

New Issue: When running `rosrun sjtu_drone start_gui` or `gzserver` the VM display goes black. I believe it is an issue with the `my_parrotdrone_openai_example` package as this does not occur with `roslaunch drone_construct main.launch` and `rosrun sjtu_drone start_gui`.

New Issue Fixed! Steps:

1. In parrotdrone_goto.py (task env), change the ROSLauncher line so it’s:
   `ROSLauncher(rospackage_name="sjtu_drone", launch_file_name="contest.launch", ros_ws_abspath=ros_ws_abspath)`
2. In parrotdrone_env.py (robot env), comment out the ROSLauncher() line.

---

Originally posted by [ltbd78](https://answers.ros.org/users/53077/ltbd78/) with karma: 16 on 2020-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0